# How can I save input text with nestable's serialize()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to fix an admin interface for a menu system that is based on jQuery nestable and PHP MySQL. Features I'm trying to achieve is nestable, sortable, rename, add and delete.

I've started out with help from [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) and `http://robertan.com/blog/?p=108` and gotten pretty far with it. See [Testsite](http://dms-server.se/js_test/menu.php)

But how can I modify it so that the values from the text inputs is also saved with the `nestable.serialize()` function.

```
serialize: function() {
    var data,
        depth = 0,
        list  = this;
        step  = function(level, depth) {
            var array = [ ],
                items = level.children(list.options.itemNodeName);

            items.each(function() {
                var li   = $(this),
                    item = $.extend({}, li.data()),
                    sub  = li.children(list.options.listNodeName);

                if (sub.length) {
                    item.children = step(sub, depth + 1);
                }
                array.push(item);
            });
            return array;
        };

    data = step(list.el.find(list.options.listNodeName).first(), depth);
    return data;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Nestable Drag-and-drop menu with MySQL in the below link http://robertan.com/blog/?p=108